# How do I retrieve an associative array with prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysqli

In the php documentation on fetching associative arrays (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) it doesn't give any examples that use prepared statements. I tried reinterpreting the code given there to use the prepared statements stuff I've done in the past which does work. But this code just errors. Is it possible then to use prepared statements for this? If so, how?

```
    <?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('website','username','pw','db');

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $startTime = 1389056400;
    $query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Start = ?");
    $query->bind_param('i', $startTime);
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    /* associative array */
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo $row["Start"];
    echo $row["End"];

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: it should work exactly the same way with prepared statements. What are the errors?

Comment: Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in D:\Hosting\11750767\html\finder\index.php on line 13.
                                                                                           

**Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in D:\Hosting\11750767\html\finder\index.php on line 16.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is an object not a string, the query function expects a string.

You shouldn't be calling the query function like that, you should be calling execute.

Try:

`$result = $query->execute();`

from here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php